# Regular expression for contents within <td>and</td>

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

I need to find a regular expression to use for finding the content within  and  tags for use in PHP. I have tried...

```
preg_split("<td>([^\"]*)</td>", $table[0]);
```

But that gives me the PHP error...

```
Warning: preg_split(): Unknown modifier '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\.....
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: btw don't parse html with regex... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: You should start and end the pattern with a delimiter, usually `/`; moreover, you have to escape `/` in `</td>`: `preg_split("/<td>([^\"]*)<\/td>/", $table[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/<td>([^\"]*)<\/td>/", $table[0], $matches);
```

But, as a general rule, *please*, [do not try to parse HTML with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that you need to do some extra work to make sure that the `*` between `<td>` and `</td>` in your regular expression doesn't slurp up entire lines of `<td>some text</td>`.  That's because `*` is pretty greedy.

To toggle off the greediness of `*`, you can put a `?` after it - this tells it just grab up until the first time it reaches whatever is after the `*`.  So, the regular expression you're looking for is something like:

```
/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/
```

Remember, since the regular expression starts and ends with a `/`, you have to be careful about any `/` that is inside your regular expression - they have to be escaped.  Hence, the `\/`.

From your regular expression, it looks like you're also trying to exclude any `"` character that might be between a `<td>` and `</td>` - is that correct?  If that were the case, you would change the regular expression to use the following:

```
/<td>([^\"]*?)<\/td>/
```

But, assuming you *don't want to exclude the `"` character in your matches*, your PHP code could look like this, using `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`.

```
preg_match_all("/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

What you're looking for is in `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` instead of `preg_split`

```
preg_match("|<td>([^<]*)</td>|", $table[0], $m);
print_r($m);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you forgot to wrap regex with delimiters. Also you shouldn't specify closing `td` tag in regex.

Try the following code. Assuming `$table[0]` contains html between `<table>`, `</table>` tags, it allows to extract any content (including html) from cells of table:

```
$a_result = array_map(
    function($v) { return preg_replace('/<\/td\s*>/i', '', $v); },
    array_slice(preg_split('/<td[^>]*>/i', $table[0]), 1)
);
```